# Sensing password protected sites when using urllib in python

Tags: python, error-handling, urllib

Hi I have a long series of urls of images (eg. `site.com/pic.jpg`) which I am retrieving in order for my program (in Python v2.6). I'm using `urllib.urlretreive()`. Sometimes the url prompts me for a username and password. So I placed `urllib.urlretreive()` in a try/except to avoid those urls but I still need to insert a fake username and password to prompt the error that triggers the try/except to skip that url. Is there a way I can sense when there is a password request and skip the url automatically? It's a very long list and I don't want to be waiting here the whole time to push enter occasionally... Thanks

Comment: In many cases you'll be able to get this info from the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the site has HTTP authentication, you need to add a header to your request to insert a username and password (fake or otherwise). Here's how you can do this using `urllib2`.

```
import base64
import urllib2

headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encodestring('[username]:[password]')}
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

This will return `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized` if the username/password is incorrect, but the server will ignore the authentication if it is not required.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that is whatever data (if any) you wish to POST to the server. If you have none, you can use an empty string.